Extract SQL Server results in JavaScript, store it in a variable, access in HTML
I am trying to extract database data in JavaScript using SQL Server. The problem now is that, after the connection close it seems that the data is not storing in the variable? I am not sure how it works.
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
const poolConnect = pool.connect()

let workid = []

function connectStart(){
  poolConnect.then(() => {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool)
  
    // 查询用户表格中的所有数据
    request.query("select  *  from  dbo.xxAIO_det where xxAIO__ch01 like '%172.168.1.70;%' order by xxAIO_NO", (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("ERROR", err)
      } else {
        console.log("Results:")
        result.recordset.forEach((row) => {
          workid.push(row.xxAIO_NO);
        })
      }
      console.log(workid)
  
      pool.close()
      
    })
})
}
connectStart()
console.log(workid)


the code seems to execute the final console log line and then start the connection, what is the problem or is this just how it behave?
[]
Results:
[ '10', '15', '20', '50' ]

I am not sure if this is the right way to get data from SQL Server, as I found this method online. The final goal is to extract the data and I need to display it in a HTML table.

You should also add the HTML and the code that connects the HTML with the data fetched from the sql server

connectStart is asynchronous, therefore the last console.log(workid) will be empty at this point

Use async/await: instead of using callbacks, you can use async/await to make your code look more synchronous. This will help you avoid the issue of the final console.log(workid) statement is executed before the query results are available.
Here is the code:
async function connectStart() {
  try {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    const poolConnect = await pool.connect();
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    const result = await request.query("select  *  from  dbo.xxAIO_det where xxAIO__ch01 like '%172.168.1.70;%' order by xxAIO_NO");
    const workid = result.recordset.map((row) => row.xxAIO_NO);
    console.log(workid);
    pool.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("ERROR", err);
  }
}
connectStart(); 

You need to adjust your code to handle the data extraction and processing accordingly.
